# Enabling JVM options with Java Web Start / JNLP

Tags: java, jvm, java-web-start, jnlp

I'm creating a Web Start application which would benefit from some of the newer JVM options (especially escape analysis, G1 garbage collector etc.)

At the same time, I would like the application to work gracefully on older JVMs that do not support these options.

Is there a good way of achieving this?

Comment: Have you read the JNLP spec as revised for Java 6u10?

Comment: Just had a look - thanks for pointer. It is not exactly clear on this point but it looks like multiple resources elements with different java-vm-args for each JVM version might work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As [Thorbjørn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53897/thorbjorn-ravn-andersen) mentioned, Java 6 u10 allows multiple `j2se` elements in JNLP.  The [**JNLP File Syntax** `resources`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#resources)  section of the latest *Java Web Start Developer's Guide*, indicates that multiple `j2se` elements, each with `java-vm-args` attributes can be specified with the most preferred occurring first.  For example:

```
<j2se version="1.3" initial-heap-size="64m" max-heap-size="128m"/>
<j2se version="1.4.2+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" 
      java-vm-args="-esa -Xnoclassgc"/>
```